# Django e Template

Tags: django, django-templates

Boa Noite!
Pessoal, estou com um problemas a 4 dias e infelizmente ainda não consegui resolver!
Estou trabalhando com tamplates no DJango, mas estou tendo problemas, pois não aparece nada nas páginas!

Essa é a estrutura básica da base.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    {% load staticfiles %}

    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block head_override %}{% endblock head_override %}


    </head>

    <body{% block body_override %}{% endblock body_override %}>


                        {% block content %}


                        {% endblock content %}

{% block extra_javascript %}


{% endblock extra_javascript %}

</body>

</html>
```

Aqui é a página html que estende "base.html". Tem mais informações na página, mas estou querendo mostrar mesmo é a Estrutura do Djando, pois acredito que o erro esteja relacionado a isso! Pois fiz o teste sem utilizar Templates do Djando e funcionou :(!!

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block title %}Google Maps{% endblock %}

{% block head_override %}

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />



{% endblock head_override %}


{% block content %}

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div onload=" initialize()" class="main-box clearfix">
            <header class="main-box-header clearfix">
                <h2>MAPA COM PONTEIROS</h2>
            </header>

            <div class="main-box-body clearfix">
                <div id="map" class="map-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>



{% endblock content %}


{% block extra_javascript %}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                zoom: 8
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                    mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

{% endblock extra_javascript %}
```

Esta é a View

```
__author__ = 'Sara Fernandes'

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import redirect # Funcao para executar um http-redirect

#from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect # Funcao para redirecionar o usuario
#Criar as Views aqui

# pagina inicial do projeto dweb

def homepage(request):
    return render_to_response('indexTEMPLATE.html',
        context_instance= RequestContext(request))


def googlemaps(request):
     return render(request, "maps.html") # redireciona o usuario para a p�gina de login

def redirecionalogin(request):
     return render(request, "login.html") # redireciona o usuario para a p�gina de login
```

settings.py

```
  """
Django settings for web project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

#PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'web',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'web.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'web.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'NAME': 'gerenciador.db',
        'USER':'', 'PASSWORD': '',
        'PORT':'', 'PORT': '',


    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web/templates'),
)
```

Comment: qual sua estrutura de diretórios?

Comment: Só uma dica @sara-fernandes, nunca revele sua SECRET_KEY

Answer (score 5):

Seu diretório templates tem que estar dentro do seu app **web** e no seu settings.py e a variável **TEMPLATES** na chave **DIRS** tem que possuir esse o path desse diretório.

```
TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [
                os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web', 'templates')
             ],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sara, você não precisa usar override, aparentemente esta tudo certo, só que, dentro do teu settings.py, delete a linha do template_dirs:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web/templates'),
)
```

porque? bem, como tua pasta do template esta dentro do teu app web, ele por padrão e reconhecido automaticamente, dentro do teu template base.html retire os `{% block body_override %}{% endblock body_override %}`, e o `{% block extra_javascript %}` tente trabalhar normalmente com js, o block content vai pegar tudo o que estiver contido dentro do body do teu html, tente utilizar o js dentro do block content assim:

```
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div onload=" initialize()" class="main-box clearfix">
        <header class="main-box-header clearfix">
            <h2>MAPA COM PONTEIROS</h2>
        </header>

        <div class="main-box-body clearfix">
            <div id="map" class="map-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>


{% endblock content %}
```

se essas modificações não derem certo, coloque teu projeto no github e poste o link aqui que tentarei te ajudar com o mesmo.